# how to update pillar package in R studio

Tags: r

I am trying to use sunburst package in R and it has a version dependency on pillar package.

When I launch my R studio in mac and select pillar and hit update, it fails to update the package. Here is the log trace

```
> install.packages("pillar")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
pillar  1.3.1  1.4.6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 113884 bytes (111 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 111 KB

* installing *source* package ‘pillar’ ...
** package ‘pillar’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
mv: rename /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pillar to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/00LOCK-pillar/pillar: Permission denied
Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) :
  problem copying ./NAMESPACE to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pillar/NAMESPACE: Permission denied
Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) :
  problem copying ./NEWS.md to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pillar/NEWS.md: Permission denied
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pillar/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/kh/9lkdq11x3sv56717v0700p_r_16f9p/T/RtmpYnmNIW/downloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone help on how to update this package?

Comment: It appears that you are on version 3.4 of R, which is 3 years old now. Can you upgrade to the latest version (4.0.2)?

Comment: yes I think I will need to do that. Though i was able to install my library by pointing it to install it to a different location